# What does "notice me senpai" mean, when a boy says it to you?

Tags: meme

So this boy in my class said to me, "notice me senpai".  What does it mean? 
   I think they like me, so does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

He wants you to notice him because he has a great admiration for you ^^

Senpai is an honorific used for experienced or older colleagues in a organization, like clubs, businesses or even schools.

All of this maybe means that this person considers you as a more important person and hopes to get attention from you.

http://www.dictionary.com/meaning/notice-me-senpai